# Xcode 7 upload to app store disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I just updated my Xcode to Xcode 7. Now I clicked my app I selected archive and now I'm getting the same window as always except my iOS app doesn't appear under iOS apps but under the Other items tab.

I also can't export it to ipa or click on submit to app store?

Someone have a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: See the [following search results for "generic archive"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxcode%5D+generic+archive). One of these should cover your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading my cocoapods to:

```
gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0.beta.3 --verbose
```

solved the problem.

Comment: This is now fixed in the release cocoapods so you can just install cocoapods.

Comment: We fixed this issue by reinstall cocoapods to the latest version.